# Can I use a servlet using "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Cmdline)" to run another program (exe file) and write to and read from text files?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, servlets, exe

I have an eclipse project (let's call it myapp.java) that is a java SWT GUI with a few text boxes and push buttons.  When the user enters the required information, it writes a text file and creates a string called command-line . It then uses the run-time command:

```
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Cmdline);
```

to execute another program, written in C (lets call this myapp.exe).  The command line contains myapp with various command line options.  This program reads the inputfile.txt and writes and outputfile.txt.

The java program then copies the file outputfile.txt into a window.

Can I make this application into a dynamic web application and place these two programs on a web-site and execute them on the host machine?  If so, what are the steps involved? I will need to run an exe file on the host machine from a java program and read and write text files on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The cmd executing part will be the same as for SWT. It should be no problem to reuse your existing code, if the SWT GUI and the cmd execution logic are are nicely separated. Of course the GUI (web) part is completely different.